# HTML Input gets cropped trough content on mobile

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a problem. I created the following topbar:

```css
#topBar {
    height: 30px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

#comboBoxAgent {
    width: 400px;
    height: 100%;
}

#comboBoxCoin1 {
    min-width: 60px;
    height: 100%;
}

#comboBoxCoin2 {
    min-width: 60px;
    height: 100%;
}

#btnToggleAgent {
    float: right;
    height: 100%;
    min-width: 60px;
    width: 70px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: white;
}

#toggleSwitch {
    height: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
}

#txtStartDateTime {
    margin-left: 10px;
}

.simulator-progress {
    font-weight: bold;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1100px) {

    #comboBoxCoin2 {
        display: none;
    }

}






#maxOrders {
    padding: 5px 0px;
}

.txtOrderRadioBtn {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    display: inline-block;
}

#maxOrdersBtn {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="topBar">
    <select id="comboBoxAgent" onchange="changeAgent()"></select>
    <select id="comboBoxCoin1" class="comboBoxCoin" onchange="loadCoinPriceData()">
        <option value="">-</option>
    </select>
    <select id="comboBoxCoin2" class="comboBoxCoin" onchange="loadCoinPriceData()">
        <option value="">-</option>
    </select>
    <div id="toggleSwitch">
        <div class="radio-group">
            <input type="radio" id="environmentReal" name="environment" checked="checked" value="Real"><label for="option-one">Real</label>
            <input type="radio" id="environmentSim" name="environment" value="Simulator"><label for="option-two">Sim</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="simulatorControls" style="display: none;">
        <input type="text" id="txtStartDateTime" placeholder="Start (0000-00-00 00:00:00)">
        <button id="btnToggleSimulator" onClick="toggleSimulator()"></button>
        <label id="txtSimulatorProgress" class="simulator-progress"></label>
    </div>

    <button id="btnToggleAgent" onClick="toggleAgent()"></button>
</div>

<div id="maxOrders">
    <label class="txtOrderRadioBtn">Max visible orders</label>
    <form id="maxOrdersBtn">
        <label class="radio-inline">
            <input type="radio" value="50" name="maxOrderOption" checked>50
        </label>
        <label class="radio-inline">
            <input type="radio" value="100" name="maxOrderOption">100
        </label>
        <label class="radio-inline">
            <input type="radio" value="250" name="maxOrderOption">250
        </label>
        <label class="radio-inline">
            <input type="radio" value="All" name="maxOrderOption">All
        </label>
    </form>
</div>
```

The snippet isn't working properly, but I think thats just because its a snippet. The point is, that when I click on the radio button `"Sim"` the input field with the datetime shows up. Now this works properly on desktop, but on my mobile device the input field goes trough the `maxOrders` div. Here is an image of the mobile result:
[image]

Now how can I fix this using media queries. There are a few things that are important for the solution. The `<button id="btnToggleAgent" onClick="toggleAgent()"></button>` has to stay in the top right corner and the maxOrders needs to be below the simulator datetime input field on mobile. Please let me know how I can fix this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do two things: Eliminate as many hard-coded widths as you can. The modern web should be flexible. Eliminate floats. They're a pain, and there are better ways (such as [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)).

Other tips:

- Use styling classes instead of IDs. This makes them reusable and forces you to consider how to simplify.
- Apply padding and spacing globally, rather than in one-offs. Use generic classes or a small library.

```css
#topBar {
  height: 30px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
}

#comboBoxAgent {
  flex: auto;
}

.comboBoxCoin1 {
  min-width: 60px;
}

#btnToggleAgent {
  min-width: 60px;
  width: 70px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: white;
}

.simulator-progress {
  font-weight: bold;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1100px) {
  #comboBoxCoin2 {
    display: none;
  }
}

#maxOrders {
  padding: 5px 0px;
}

.txtOrderRadioBtn {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

#maxOrdersBtn {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div id="topBar">
  <select id="comboBoxAgent" onchange="changeAgent()"></select>
  
  <select id="comboBoxCoin1" class="comboBoxCoin" onchange="loadCoinPriceData()">
    <option value="">-</option>
  </select>
  
  <select id="comboBoxCoin2" class="comboBoxCoin" onchange="loadCoinPriceData()">
    <option value="">-</option>
  </select>
  
  <div id="toggleSwitch">
    <div class="radio-group">
      <input type="radio" id="environmentReal" name="environment" checked="checked" value="Real"><label for="option-one">Real</label>
      <input type="radio" id="environmentSim" name="environment" value="Simulator">           <label for="option-two">Sim</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div id="simulatorControls" style="display: none;">
    <input type="text" id="txtStartDateTime" placeholder="Start (0000-00-00 00:00:00)">
    <button id="btnToggleSimulator" onClick="toggleSimulator()"></button>
    <label id="txtSimulatorProgress" class="simulator-progress"></label>
  </div>

  <button id="btnToggleAgent" onClick="toggleAgent()"></button>
</div>

<div id="maxOrders">
  <label class="txtOrderRadioBtn">Max visible orders</label>
  <form id="maxOrdersBtn">
    <label class="radio-inline">
            <input type="radio" value="50" name="maxOrderOption" checked>50
        </label>
    <label class="radio-inline">
            <input type="radio" value="100" name="maxOrderOption">100
        </label>
    <label class="radio-inline">
            <input type="radio" value="250" name="maxOrderOption">250
        </label>
    <label class="radio-inline">
            <input type="radio" value="All" name="maxOrderOption">All
        </label>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, just one thing.... I understand what you said about not using hard-coded widths, but now the first select option box is max-width on full window, which doesn't look good on desktop. Shouldn't I use something like percentage or viewwidth as width there to prevent it?

Comment: Yes, use min- and max-widths, or use the tools flexbox provides to spread elements more uniformly.

Comment: So I can use for example: `max-width: 400px;` on `comboBoxAgent`?